# jQuery replace brackets in title

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm looking to strip out some contents from the page `<title>` on click with JavaScript.

Before: `(1) Hello World` (value in brackets can change)

After: `Hello World`

What would be the best `document.title.replace()` regex to capture this `(1)` part (with a space after it)?

Comment: How much of "(1) " is *always* going to look exactly like that? That's kind-of an important detail.

Comment: It will only ever be a positive value, not `(0)` or `()` for example.

Comment: In first place, why/how it is added to the title?

Comment: It's a notifications output, added in the HTML (not with JS).

Comment: `document.title = document.title.split(')').pop().trim();`

Comment: What's not working in your current regex?

Comment: @adeneo that's working great, could you post as an answer?

Comment: Just note that it only works if you don't have `)` anywhere else in your title, but I guessed that would be unlikely.

Comment: Yup, that's fine. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
document.title.replace(/\(\d+\)\s/, '')
```

So this matches a string starting with a `(`, then one or more of a digit, then `)` and finally a space. This will match `(1)` or even `(556)`.